# Python Kill all child processes when main process is killed

Tags: python, multiprocessing

The main process creates a couple of child processes by using multiprocessing.Process(). The child process also creates a child process of its own. Here is the sample code:

```
import multiprocessing

class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def print_info(self):
        proc_name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
        print 'Consumer %s has producer %s' % (proc_name, self.name)

def consumer(q):
    task = q.get()
    task.print_info()

def producer():

    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    proc_name = multiprocessing.current_process().name

    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=consumer, args=(queue,))
    child_proc_name = p.name

    print 'Producer %s has consumer %s' % (proc_name, child_proc_name)

    p.start()

    queue.put(MyClass(name=proc_name))

    queue.close()
    queue.join_thread()
    p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    procs = []

    for _ in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=producer, args=())
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)

    for p in procs:
        p.join()
```

My question is mainly about how to clean up all processes when the program exit with issues. The issue could be process killed by signals or some child process gets exceptions. I basically want to clean up all processes if any process is killed with problems. I am using python2.7.

Answer (score 0):

The [`daemon`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.daemon) flag to is what you need. Daemon child processes will be killed if the main process exits.

To do the other way around, the only portable way is to let the parent periodically check if the children are still running via their [`is_alive`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.is_alive) method.